# A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-firebase_messaging'. > compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just installed the firebase messaging service on my react native application, after installing the module I get this error when compiling :`FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/fredy/Bureau/monapp/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/android/build.gradle' line: 75
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-firebase_messaging'.

> No signature of method: firebase_json_c54o9pv7otjdf4v6o99zlwlkv$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (String, Boolean) values: [messaging_auto_init_enabled, true]
> Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object), findAll(), findAll()

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-firebase_messaging'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

`
help me please

Comment: having the same problem. It's been 3 Days now.   :(

Comment: @AmanDeep Having the same issue, It's been 2 days now :( did you get to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update all your `@react-native-firebase/` modules in your package.json.

Then `npm i` and build again.